# jquery .each() to replace all alements that have a class with regex

Tags: jquery

I want to the replace the html content of all instances of a class, with a regex :

```
$('ul#chosenmodel-menu').find("a.ui-link-inherit:contains(SMALL-WAVE)").each().html(function(idx,oldHtml){
    return oldHtml.replace(/SMALL/, "blablablablabla");
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove that `.each()` it wont need here,

```
$('ul#chosenmodel-menu').find("a.ui-link-inherit:contains(SMALL-WAVE)").html(function(idx,oldHtml){
    return oldHtml.replace(/SMALL/, "blablablablabla");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul#chosenmodel-menu').find("a.ui-link-inherit:contains(SMALL-WAVE)").each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/SMALL/, "blablablablabla"));
});
```